# Getting Count of sp_helpindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How do I get count of the below sp?

```
EXEC sp_helpindex 'dbo.MachineLog'
```

I want the count of the results.
Can anyone help with the syntax.

I tried below :-

```
select Count(*) from 
EXEC sp_helpindex 'dbo.MachineLog'
```

Comment: `INSERT` the data into a [temporary] table [variable], then `COUNT` the rows in that table.

Comment: An alternative is to replicate what `sp_helpindex` is doing with help of the system catalog views (`sys.schemas`, `sys.tables`, `sys.columns`, `sys.indexes`, `sys.index_columns`). This removes the need for intermediate tables and can also have performance benefits if you're querying less than what `sp_helpindex` normally does. This query in particular is as simple as `select count(*) from sys.indexes where object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MachineLog')` (though joining with `sys.tables` is cleaner still).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Above provided query helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sp_helpindex` itself is a procedure, you can execute insert its result to a temp table and select from the temp table like this

```
Declare @Tbl Table (index_name varchar(128),index_desc varchar(512), index_keys varchar(16))
Insert @Tbl Exec sp_helpindex 'dbo. MachineLog' 
Select count(*) from @Tbl
```